# Presto take monthly average

Tags: sql, average, aggregate-functions, presto, date-arithmetic

- I would like to take the average number of monthly `number_of_listings` for each `merchant_id`.
- The table below shows for each `merchant_id` the daily `number_of_listings`

**Main table**

```
date          merchant_id   number_of_listings
2019-02-01    12            325
2019-02-02    12            332
2019-02-03    12            235
2019-02-04    12            393
2019-02-05    12            484
2019-02-06    12            383
2019-02-07    12            434
```

**Output table**

```
month          merchant_id   average_number_of_listings
2019-02        12            400
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a simple aggregate query. You can use [date function `date_trunc()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_trunc), that returns the first day of the month:

```
select
    date_trunc('month', date) date_month,
    merchant_id
    avg(number_of_listings) average_number_of_listings
from mytable
group by date_trunc('month', date), merchant_id
```